# SQLAlchemy Column. Существует ли возможность присоединения таблицы с идентификацией сущности?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

У меня есть 2 таблицы с разными сущностями. Эти сущности необходимо присоединить к третьей таблице.

**Сущности:**

1. Item

| id | sku | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some_sku | some_name |

2. Sale

| id | date | fiscal_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | some_date | some_fiscal_id |

**И третья таблица, которая должна содержать ссылки на сущности**
Хочу, чтобы моя таблица выглядела примерно так, если это возможно:

| id | entity | entity_id | extension | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sale | 1 | some_extension | some_value |
| 2 | item | 1 | some_extension | some_value |

*Обратите внимание на колонку "entity", которая по моему мнению должна выступать идентификатором сущности для entity_id*

**Вопрос:**

1. Возможно ли это в SQLite?
2. Возможно ли связывать таблицы таким образом, испольуя SQLAlchemy?

Comment: + за оформление таблиц в markdown) Напишите конкретнее, используя какой столбец хотите объединить. И желательно расширить входные данные, добавить ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов 
В моих представлениях entity должен содержать идентификатор сущности, а entity_id - id из соответствующей таблицы.

Ожидаемый результат - в первой таблице уже представлен.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Обновил описание...

Comment: @insolor спасибо, поправил. Буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 1):

Решил использовать sqlalchemy.ext.declarative [ConcreteBase](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/inheritance/concrete.html)
Для решения, его необходимо добавить в ваши сущности.

> Пример есть по ссылке.